# Why does the taylor series of $\frac {1}{\ln x}$ have a non-infinite radius of convergence?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Shouldn't the taylor series of a function be equal to that function for any input value?

Why does this not work for the taylor series of $\frac {1}{\ln x}$ when $|x| \gt 1$?

Edit: I do mean the series taken about $x_o = 2$

Comment: I assume this is the Taylor series develped around $x_0=2$?

Comment: Also, even where i converges, the Taylor series may differ from the original function

Comment: the given function is not an entire function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function
hence its taylor series does not converge everywhere.

Comment: A Laruent series expansion is possible about $x = 1$; namely $$\frac{1}{\log x} = \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{x-1}{12} + \frac{(x-1)^2}{24} - \frac{19(x-1)^3}{720} + \frac{3(x-1)^4}{160} + \cdots.$$

Comment: I would argue that a more natural point about which to take the Taylor series expansion would be $x = e$, giving $$1-\frac{x-e}{e}+\frac{3 (x-e)^2}{2 e^2}-\frac{7 (x-e)^3}{3
   e^3}+\frac{11 (x-e)^4}{3 e^4}-\frac{347 (x-e)^5}{60 e^5}+\frac{3289
   (x-e)^6}{360 e^6}-\cdots.$$

Comment: @heropup I thought the same, but since $e > 1$, that series diverges as well. But the series about $x=\frac {1}{e}$ is not horrible

Answer (score 2):

Not all Taylor Series have the ability to converge for all $x$ values.

For example, the Taylor Series of $\ln(x+1)$ about $x_0=0$ is

$$\ln(x+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$

Which doesn't converge for $x>1$.  We can see that if $x>1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}n$ does not converge, so the summation will not converge.

So not all Taylor Series converge for all $x$, but if you could evaluate it like a Ramanujan sum, you might be able to get some right values from it.

Answer (score -4):

Note that the Taylor expansion is
$$\dfrac{1}{\ln{x}}=-\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k(x-1)^k}{k}} \quad \text{for}\quad\!\!\! |x-1|<1 $$

To address your question, the Taylor series is limited by the values of $x$ that make the series converge. So, even if the original expression has domain $(0,1),(1,\infty)$, the Taylor series does not necessarily follow.

Comment: That expression is most certainly **not** a Taylor series expansion, which must be of the form $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k.$$